# calling rest api from azure healthbot using JS

Tags: azure-bot-service

I am trying to make a call to a REST endpoint using JS code from the Azure health-bot service,

I am making use of the request-promise package which is whitelisted in the MS doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/healthbot/scenario-authoring/advanced_functionality#white-listed-packages

var request = require('request-promise');

However I am getting the following error: "**Usage of the 'request-promise' package is not allowed. Please contact your system administrator**"

Do you know:
1. Why I am getting this error?
2. how can I make a REST call from a JS script?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your question "from the Azure health-bot service".  Do you mean you are in a Healthbot scenario and trying to make this call?  if so, you don't just code it in javascript in an Action step, you add a Data Connection step to your dialog flow.

Comment: I want to call the API from an event handler like this:

bot.on("event", function (event) {
    // call api

    bot.send(msg);
})